# What is the Relaese date for Microsoft Orleans which can support service fabric?

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric, orleans

We are planning to introduce Microsoft Orleans to our Service Fabric Cluster, but we observed some limitation in existing Orleans, as per few documentation Microsoft.Orleans.Clustering.ServiceFabric is not available since the release of orleans 2.0.
So can we know by when a new version will be released which is capable to host in Service Fabric?

We believe the new version supports both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Orleans documentation site is still being updated/rebuilt after the 2.0 release and a number of pages can only be found via search. I searched the documentation site for "Service Fabric" and found the following:

http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/deployment/service_fabric_hosting.html

It appears the NuGet package has been renamed to `Microsoft.Orleans.Hosting.ServiceFabric`.

Additionally, a sample project using Service Fabric hosting can be found here:

https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/tree/master/Samples/2.0/ServiceFabric

Comment: Check out [GitHub PR #5666](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/pull/5666). Even though the PR removed an old, unmaintained package... it still includes a comment that confirms current Service Fabric support. It even indicates Microsoft is using Orleans with Service Fabric internally.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see Service fabric support available for Orleans 2.0.
Please post this as a product feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric).

This allows you to get direct feedback on your request from engineering, and will also allow other customers to vote it up for prioritization.